# oninput i want to fix decimal fix to 2 but onchange it is working

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function validate(e) {
  e.target.value = parseFloat(e.target.value).toFixed(2)
}
```

```html
<input oninput=this.validate/>
```

Comment: `this.validate` should be `validate(this)`

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're asking, could you elaborate a little? Are you saying that your code works with `onchange` but it stops working as soon as you change `onchange` to `oninput`?

Comment: yeah. .if we  want to enter  98.76 and it shows 9.00 for oninput

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use onkeyup instead. and you need to delay update, so that user can enter number. debounce.

**// HTML**

```
<input onkeyup="validate(this)" type="number"/>
```

**// JS**

```
function validate(e) {
    console.log(e.value)
    setTimeout(() => {
        const val = parseFloat(e.value);
        if (val !== NaN)
            e.value = parseFloat(e.value).toFixed(2)
    }, 500)
}
```

// Sample:

```js
function validate(e) {
    
    setTimeout(() => {
        const val = parseFloat(e.value);
        if (val !== NaN)
            e.value = parseFloat(e.value).toFixed(2)
    }, 500)
}
```

```html
<input onkeyup="validate(this)" type="number"/>
```

Comment: onkeyup, keypres.. Many check my solutions.. Based on ur need u can modify. On press if u want to modify on fly. Up when u give user time to type. Debounce for better UX

Comment: after del all the numbers it throws NAN

Answer (score 0):

Try onchange event in javascript

```js
function validate(e) {
  e.value = parseFloat(e.value).toFixed(2)
}
```

```html
<input onchange="validate(this)" id="number"  type="number"/>
```

Comment: They want to do it on input, not on change. And your function will only work with a single element ID, not any element.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `event` when calling the `validate` function. Also, you should remove `this` keyword:

```js
function validate(e) {
  e.target.value = parseFloat(e.target.value).toFixed(2)
}
```

```html
<input oninput="validate(event)"/>
```

Also, I suggest using `onblur` instead of `oninput`. because using oninput in this scenario make the user unable to input a number properly.

Comment: what if we want to enter 93.45

Answer (score 0):

`this.validate` is wrong because `validate` is not a method of the input element, it's an ordinary top-level function. Also, you forgot the parentheses, so you didn't even call the method.

You need to call it, and pass `this` as an argument. Since you're passing `this`, you don't need to use `e.target`, you can just use `e`.

```js
function validate(e) {
  e.value = parseFloat(e.value).toFixed(2)
}
```

```html
<input oninput="validate(this)"/>
```

However, doing this validation on input won't work well. You can't delete digits after the decimal point, because it will keep adding back zeroes to make it 2 digits. You should just do it with `onchange`.